# Use images having unique .jar file (Slick 2D)

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, slick2d

Im trying to create an executable jar file of my mini game created with the library slick2D.
I found out that using JarSplice we can merge multiple jar into just one "fat jar"

The problem is: when I run the generated fat jar I get this error and I can't get to load images...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not
>   found: file:
>   /C:/Users/b.daepp/Desktop/F/Football.jar!/foot/img/field.jpg

I started with the standard way described in the tutorials of slick

```
Image i = new Image("img/name.png");
```

Since in the fat jar there is no classpath I tried many solutions and the last is:

```
Image i = new Image(
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/package/img/name.png").getFile()));
```

The error never changed, no way to use those images
Please help

Comment: I would recommend to use absolute path for resources (so /foot/img/field.jpg) and check that in the jar there is indeed an image file located at the path /foot/img/field.jpg

Comment: Does http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource help?